# Checking values in a parent object

Tags: oop, user-interface, lua

Recently, I have been working on a game project and decided to learn how to make a gui from scratch in love2d while I was at it. I decided to use OOP where I had menu objects and button objects within the menu objects. I had a problem where I only wanted to draw the buttons only if the menu was active. The easiest/best way to do this is probably to have a function in the menu object that checks if the menu is active and draw the buttons if it is like this...

```
menu = {
 -- menu stuff
button = require("path")
active = false,
buttons = {}
} 
function menu.newButton()
--create new button object from button table
end    
function menu:drawButton()

   if self.active then
       for k,v in pairs(buttons)
          menu.buttons[k]:draw() -- some draw function that sets the size, pos, and color of the button
       end
   end 
end
```

This got me wondering though. Is there some way to check values in the menu's table from a function located in the button's table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use composition to access properties of Menu object from a Button. To do that you would need to pass a reference to the `menu` object when constructing every new Button. For instance:

```
Button = {}

function Button.new (menu)
   return setmetatable({menu = menu}, {__index = Button})
end

function Button:getMenuName()
   return self.menu.name
end

menu = {
   name = "menu1",
   buttons = {},
}

function menu:newButton ()
   local button = Button.new(self)
   table.insert(self.buttons, button)
   return button
end

local btn = menu:newButton()
print(btn:getMenuName())
```

Would print the property `name` of `menu` from object `btn`.

Comment: Sorry it took me a few days to reply. I am not terribly comfortable with metatables yet, but now that I've done some more learning about metastable this makes a lot of sense.